# Javascript 10 minute countdown timer NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery

so on Shopify store i'm trying to do a countdown timer, but when it hits 0 it should write 0, instead sometimes it writes NaN and sometimes it works and writes 0.
Does anyone know what is wrong?
Here is the code:

```js
var tenMinutesLater = new Date();
var theTimerSet = new Date();


var myTimer = localStorage.getItem("myCountDown");
console.log(myTimer);
if (myTimer === null) {
  tenMinutesLater.setMinutes(tenMinutesLater.getMinutes() + 10);
  localStorage.setItem("myCountDown", tenMinutesLater);
  theTimerSet = tenMinutesLater.getTime();
} else {
  theTimerSet = new Date(myTimer).getTime();
}


var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = theTimerSet - now;

  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("the-timer").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("the-timer").innerHTML = "0";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="timer" id="the-main-timer">
  Checkout within the next <em><span class="the-timer" id="the-timer"></span> minutes</em> to avoid losing your order.
</div>
```

Comment: Which part is writing NaN, the log or the HTML?

Comment: The HTML is writing NaN

Comment: Nan minutes Nan seconds like this? You can put a few console.log() for distance and now and update the ques accordingly.

Comment: What about changing `<` to `<=`:  `if (distance <= 0) {...}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem form me, changing this:

```
if (myTimer === null) {...
```

to this:

```
if( myTimer === null || myTimer == 'null'){
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution, since the time should be shown only if distance is bigger than 1000, since distance is in ms, not in s.

```
  if (distance < 1000) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("the-timer").innerHTML = "0";
  }else{
document.getElementById("the-timer").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think found it, the value does not exist in localstorage.

Where `myTimer` is undefined and with that undefined === null will be false.

```
var myTimer = localStorage.getItem("myCountDown");  // -> undefined
```

Then here we are creating Date with undefined and getting time where the result is NaN

```
var theTimerSet = new Date(myTimer).getTime(); // -> NaN
```

Then when NaN - [some number] will be undefined

```
var distance = theTimerSet - now; // -> undefined
```

Where again Math.floor of undefined is NaN

```
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); // -> NaN
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); // -> NaN
```

And this will show you NaN in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your NaN error.
In my opinion this must have come from when retrieving the date saved in the LocalStorage with a string / number conflict.

putting a date in local storage is not useful, you just need to keep its `.getTime()` value, since you have to redo this comparison every cycle.

you also use 2 variables (`tenMinutesLater` and `theTimerSet`) for the same thing, which may be the source of your problem as well

So I rewrote your code...
<sub>remarks :</sub>
*— I can't leave a variable named 'X' in my code.*
*— I use the Whitesmiths style (please respect it, and yes I have my own beautifier for that)*

```js
const 
  OneSec     = 1000
, OneMin      = OneSec * 60
, OneHour      = OneMin * 60
, theTimer      = document.getElementById('the-timer')
, lsName         = 'myCountDown'
, lsValue         = localStorage.getItem(lsName) 
, tenMinutesTarget = lsValue ? parseInt(lsValue) : new Date().getTime() + 10 * OneMin
  ;
if (!lsValue) localStorage.setItem(lsName, tenMinutesTarget)
  ;
let intvlRef = setInterval(()=>
  {
  let
    deltaTime = tenMinutesTarget - new Date().getTime()
  , minutes   = Math.floor((deltaTime % OneHour) / OneMin )
  , seconds   = Math.floor((deltaTime % OneMin) / OneSec  )
    ;
  theTimer.textContent = (deltaTime > 0) ? `${minutes}m ${seconds}s ` : '0 ';

  if (deltaTime < 0)
    {
    clearInterval(intvlRef)
    // localStorage.removeItem(lsName)  // ?
    }
  }, 250)
```

```
<div class="timer" id="the-main-timer">
  Checkout within the next
  <em>
    <span class="the-timer" id="the-timer"></span>
    minutes
  </em>
  to avoid losing your order.
</div>
```